# What is the probability of pulling exactly one $k^{th}$ labeled ball on the $k^{th}$ try?

Tags: probability

I have a more complex problem that I'm trying to simplify. So if I have labeled balls from $1$ to $n$, and I am pulling all the balls from the urn, what is the probability of getting $1$ ball with label $k$ on the $k^{th}$ try? I was thinking that there are n pulls, and having one on the $k^{th}$ try can be $C_n^{1}$, so basically $n$ different ways, and the other balls' permutations give me how those can differ. So that is $(n - 1)!$. The overall possibilities of how I can get a result is $n!$. But that gives me the probability of 1, which shouldn't be the case.

Comment: So the more complex problem is actually at least one ball, but I tried to simplify it with exactly one ball, than the same way with two balls, etc. Then I should just give the probabilities of those I guess.

Comment: See [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement)

Comment: @BalogSzilárd the problem with "exactly $k$ balls" is in fact the harder problem compared to the "at least $1$ ball" problem.  The traditional answer for the "exactly" problem commonly uses the answer to the at least one problem or the none problem.

Comment: @BalogSzilárd After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

There are $n!$ possibilities in total and $$!n:=n!\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$ of them are [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

So the probability on *at least one* such pull equals:$$1-\frac{!n}{n!}=1-\sum_{i=0}^n\frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

The probability of *exactly one* will equal: $$\frac{n\times!(n-1)}{n!}$$

(if the ball with label $k$ is drawn at try $k$ and it is the only one then the other $n−1$ balls must take care of a derangement together.)

Comment: Should the last expression be $\dfrac{!(n-1)}{(n-1)!}$?  There are $n$ ways to choose $k$, times $!(n-1)$ derangements of the other balls, divided by $n!$.

Comment: Extending this to the problem alluded to in the comments of *exactly two* or in general *exactly $k$* balls matched, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose which the matching balls are and then $!(n-k)$ ways to arrange the remaining balls so that they don't match, giving $\binom{n}{k}\frac{!(n-k)}{n!}$

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, you are right. Thank you for attending me. I repaired.

Comment: I don't really understand why can't I simply use permutations instead of derangements? If I am counting the possibilities of pulling $3$ on the $3^{th}$ try, the remaining $(n-1)$ "slots" should have a quantity of $(n-1)!$, isn't it? That's essentially saying how could you pair up $n$ numbers so that there is not two which are the same. And their order should be different as well. How is permutations different from derangements? What is the difference in this particular case?

Comment: A derangement is a *special* kind of permutation. If you are e.g. working with $n=3$ and for exactly one $k\in\{1,2,3\}$ a $k$-labeled ball is drawn at the $k$-th try then there are $3$ possibilities for the order of the labels: $132,321,213$. So not $n(n-1)!=3\cdot2!=6$ possibilities. Do you agree?

Comment: Oh, yes! Because, if let's say you switch the remaining two drawns, you get to all of them match with the corresponding $k$ , right And that is saying at least one pull to match, not exactly one.